# When should you use Page.DataBind() versus Control.DataBind()?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

In ASP.NET, you can bind controls individually (i.e. `GridView1.DataBind()`) or you can call `Page.DataBind()` to bind all controls on the page.

Is there any specific difference between the two calls?  Are there times when one should be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For choosing between `Page.DataBind()` versus `Control.DataBind()`, here is the Microsoft [guidance](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) :

> "Both methods work similarly. The main
>   difference is that all data sources
>   are bound to their server controls
>   after the `Page.DataBind` method is
>   called. No data is rendered to the
>   control until you explicitly call
>   either the `DataBind` method of the Web
>   server control or until you invoke the
>   page-level `Page.DataBind` method.
>   Typically, `Page.DataBind` (or `DataBind`)
>   is called from the `Page_Load` event."

There will be cases when you want specify control databinding individually, depending on the current page scenario.  For a detailed level of control over which controls are bound and when controls are bound, I opt for the control-level `DataBind()` methods.

Answer (score 12):

`Page.DataBind` *is* `Control.DataBind`. Neither the `Page` class, nor the `TemplateControl` class overrides `Control.DataBind`.

`Control.DataBind` does little more than call `OnDataBinding` for the control, then it calls `DataBind` for each child control.

Comment: That's why I asked :) - just in case there was some special case I was not aware of.

Comment: And there is the new thing I learned today - I didn't realize System.Web.UI.Page derived from System.Web.UI.Control.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

In an ASP.NET page, you can bind directly to public/protected properties of your page's code-behind class. For example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"><%#HtmlUtility.HtmlEncode(MyProperty.ToString())%></form>
```

In this case, there is no specific control to call .DataBind() on - the page itself is the control. It just so happens that calling Page.DataBind() will also call DataBind() on all child controls, so if you're already doing a Page.DataBind(), there's no need to data bind the controls individually.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to subtilities between the two calls, but
about `DataBind()` vs `Page.DataBind()` I would like to share an interesting experience which may also really guide you to chose between both :

I just spent one complete day to figure why Ajax calls and events in a huge webapplication were broken (`ItemCommand` not raised on callbacks and postbacks, lost references, etc).

The reason was I had one ASCX which made a call to `Page.DataBind()` rather than `DataBind()` on itself.

It could seem obvious when you found it, but when you are dealing with weird behavior in a >500000 lines application and a lot of complexity in master/pages/controls, it's not.
So beware of `Page.DataBind()` if you call it at the wrong place !