# Call C# Function Inside asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that is called getUserID and I would like to pass the user ID via NavigateUrl within asp:HyperLink.

This is my hyperlink:

```
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkMyAccount" Text="My Account" 
                NavigateUrl="~/Users/View.aspx" style="color:White" CssClass="myAreaLink" 
                Runat="server" Font-Size="Small" />
                &nbsp;|&nbsp;
```

I tried this but it did not work:

```
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkMyAccount" Text="My Account" 
                NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Users/View.aspx" + CPDManagement._code.SearchSelection.getUserID().Tables[0].Rows[0]["u_ID"].ToString() %> style="color:White" CssClass="myAreaLink" 
                Runat="server" Font-Size="Small" />
                &nbsp;|&nbsp;
```

Comment: are you trying to show multiple HyperLink controls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing it in the code behind?

```
if(Page.IsPostBack)
{
    lnkMyAccount.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/Users/View.aspx?UserID={0}", myUserID); 
}
```

So it will just programmatically overwrite the navigation URL

Does that work for you?

You might be able to get the `<%# .. %>` data binding syntax to work by calling data bind on the page i.e.

```
if(Page.IsPostBack)
{
    Page.DataBind();
}
```

I would do the first way though

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, this is on the master page as one of the "tab links" I was just trying to avoid doing it in the code behind...

Comment: No probs - you could always do Page.Master.FindControl to get at the link

Comment: I actually got it working by just placing Page.DataBind() and it worked. Could this Page.DataBind() cause any issues by placing it in the Page_Load()?

Comment: That's where i would put it - with the !Page_Load clause. But it will bind all the controls and if you have a grid view then it will bind too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603398/when-should-you-use-page-databind-versus-control-databind. You could try lnkMyAccount.DataBind() - i believe this works from ASP.Net 3.5 and up

Answer (score 2):

try now 
you missed `'` before the style.

I hope you are in bind mode.(inside a repeater...)

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkMyAccount" Text="My Account" 
                NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Users/View.aspx" + CPDManagement._code.SearchSelection.getUserID().Tables[0].Rows[0]["u_ID"].ToString() %> ' style="color:White" CssClass="myAreaLink" 
                Runat="server" Font-Size="Small" />
```

### edit

it does work

maybe something wrong with your CPDmanagement ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah I noticed that I missed one ' but it still did not work. It did not even make the link hyperlinked after I did this.

Comment: Royi, Could it be because I don't have it within a Repeater nor in the Binding mode?

Comment: is there a way to do it without being in a Repeater or Bind Mode?

Comment: @nick no. since you using '#' + server side functions inside a server side tag.

Comment: It is possible without repeater. Since you could use the run time Hyperlink control creation in loop and assign the desired value

Comment: By placing Page.DataBind() in my Page_Load() the original code worked... Could this cause any issues by doing it this way?

Comment: @nick The main difference is that all data sources are bound to their server controls after the Page.DataBind method is called. so if you have multpile bindable sources - they will all run

Comment: ahh got it. Thanks much for your help I got it working by just binding the lnkMyAccount :)

Answer (score 1):

use `asp:Linkbutton`, and supply your desired value to the `commandArgument` property

ex:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnMyLink" runat="server" commandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try with Below code.

### HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" onrowdatabound="grd_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="delete" runat="server" Text='<%#GetData().Rows[0][0].ToString() %>' CommandName="delete"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

### Code Behind

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn DC = new DataColumn("Test");
    Dt.Columns.Add(DC);

    DataRow Dr = Dt.NewRow();
    Dr["Test"] = "1";
    Dt.Rows.Add(Dr);
    return Dt;//.Rows[0]["test"].ToString();
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grd.DataSource = GetData();
    grd.DataBind();
}
```

---